# I am a pansexual trans/gender-fluid person

Tags: word-choice, terminology, gender-neutral, sexual-minorities

There's a risk of me potentially offending someone but I am an outsider trying to get to grips with this terminology. Online, I read someone who identified themself as a

> *pansexual trans/gender-fluid person*

I'd like to know if my understanding of the following terms is generally correct.

I just about get the difference between a *transsexual* and a *transgender*. The former is someone who has undergone a sex change that matches their personality and psychological identity, whereas a transgender does not necessarily have their sexual organs altered by surgery to match the sex they feel is theirs from birth.

I believe that a *gender fluid* person is someone who can fluctuate between feeling male or female, or they perceive to have the characteristics of both sexes within themselves and as such, they do not assign themselves a specific sex.

However, I'm not entirely sure what a pansexual is. Online research suggests it is someone who is sexually attracted and has sexual intercourse with either sex, i.e. male and female persons. But isn't that the same as a bisexual?

(*pansexual* in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansexuality))

> **Pansexuality**, or omnisexuality, is the sexual, romantic or emotional attraction towards people regardless of their sex or gender identity. Pansexual people may refer to themselves as gender-blind, asserting that gender and sex are not determining factors in their romantic or sexual attraction to others.

And [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pansexual) define ***pansexual*** as

> *adjective*
>   Not limited in sexual choice with regard to biological sex, gender, or gender identity.

The term *pansexual* has its origin in 1917 and is a compound of *pan-* meaning "all" and *-sexual*, of or related to sex.

Yet, the definition of the older term *[bisexual](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bisexual)*, first recorded in 1815–25 **but whose meaning of "attracted to both sexes" is from 1914**, is very similar to that of *pansexual*.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bisexual?s=t) and Oxford Dictionaries:

> **bisexual**
>   noun 4. a person who is romantically or sexually attracted to both men and women, or to people of various gender identities; ambisexual.

***[bisexual](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bisexual)***

> • *adjective* Sexually attracted not exclusively to people of one particular gender; attracted to both men and women.
>   • *noun*  A person who is sexually attracted not exclusively to people of one particular gender.

**Q 1.** What *is* the difference between a *bisexual* and a *pansexual*?

**Q 2.** I understand that the term *gender-fluid* was created for those who do not want to be defined as a man or woman, but *gender-fluid* has many derivatives: *agender*, *nongendered*, *genderless*, and *genderfree*.  Why is there no agreement in the [LGTBQ](http://languageofinclusion.com/what-does-lbtbq-mean-the-l-q-of-lgtbq/) community for a single, simple term to express this gender and sexual preference?

Comment: Of course, one who goes with a pansexual trans/gender-fluid person, what else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a NARQ. It's not about the English language but about logic.

Comment: @Kris no it's also about terminology and what these words mean in English.

Comment: You already know what *pan-* stands for.

Comment: For users who might be confused as to what NARQ stands for, it's Not A Real Question. A somewhat obsolete term used some time ago in EL&U's past.

Comment: The thing that's most "fluid" about this is the terminology.  The terms are not well-defined.

Comment: @HotLicks that goes for all of the English language, note this sentence from the [Oxford Dictionaries website](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2016/10/25/essex-girl/): _Our role is always ‘descriptive not prescriptive’: Oxford Dictionaries describe language as it is used, rather than seeking to determine how it should be used._ This as opposed to many therms in science, most of which have been concisely defined when first used.

Comment: @JJJ - The problem with terms (or is it "therms") of sexuality is that people often feel that the available lexicon does not fit their particular case, or that the currently "accepted" term is somehow derogatory (or simply imprecise).  So they pick new terms.  Though this is certainly within the rights of the individual, it makes the ordinary imprecision of English definitions several orders of magnitude worse.

Comment: @HotLicks "therms" is a typo. Still, the 'fluidity' of the terminology is inherent to the English language. While the terms in this question, or many other niche terms in English, are not well-defined, it may be interesting to know how the words are used.

Comment: I’ve listened to self-identifying bi- and pansexual people explaining the difference between the two to me, and I’m still not clear on the practical difference either. Truth be told, I’m not sure most of them are, either. Mostly, it seems to come down to which word (and which connotations) a given person prefers.

Comment: I think Q1 is valid (so I'm voting to reopen), but Q2 is certainly not answerable on the basis of language and is probably not answerable even by the QUILTBANG community itself (as evidenced by the simple fact that they keep expanding their acronym).

Comment: @Hellion thank you. I would delete the second question but it has been answered by two users, and such a drastic edit would be unjustifiable on my part.

Comment: Great question, unfortunate closure, happy reopening.  For potential re-closers, as is usual, this is not a POB question. The words themselves may be vague or in flux, but objective answers about that vagueness or change can be made.

Comment: The problem is that many of these terms come with a social/political agenda and aren't neutral terms for particular sexual preferences/behaviors/identities, so they're not going to make much sense if one attempts to treat them as such.

Comment: @KarlG I appreciate the complexities but one could still explain why pansexual was "created" hard on the heels of *bisexual*, and why it is seemingly in vogue nowadays. And... what the fundamental difference between the two is. Plenty to say and learn.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [hard on the heels?](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bisexual%2C+pansexual&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). 'bisexual' has been very common for years, and only recently has pansexual been used as a distinct but related concept.

Comment: Note that 'pansexual' used to have a different definition (as used in Freudian psychiatry): ["defined as how sexual energy and desire is the basis for all human interaction in life."](https://everydayfeminism.com/2014/11/pansexuality-101/)

Comment: @Mitch  the "hard on the heels" *comment* was referring to the year "pansexual" was coined,  shortly after bisexual was used to mean "sexually attracted to both sexes". I meant that, and there's a limit to how much research one is expected to do before posting a question. I could have posted 300 questions if I didn't always feel I have to "justify" the legitimacy of a question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Oh. So pan- and bi- were probably coined at exactly the same time by Freud, is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Mitch I don't know who precisely coined these terms, and I don't see how you arrived at that conclusion. Maybe you should look at the question, I edited it since you last looked.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I thought I saw something that implied that the two words were introduced in the same work, but I think I am mistaken. From googling it does seem like [Wilhelm Fliess](http://www.terrapsych.com/freud.html) suggested the term to Freud. As to pansexuality, all sorts of claims that Freud coined it (to mean something other than what is meant now), but no indication I could find of where or when.

Comment: But...did you see the wiki paragraph on the[comparison between pan- and bi- sexuality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansexuality#Comparison_to_bisexuality_and_other_sexual_identities)? I feel like that comes close to an answer.

Comment: Mari-Lou A, it simply doesn't work that way.

In logic, you might be male or female, gay or bi or some explicable combination of those.

In this special world in which you're operating, logic has no meaning. Everything is self-defined until someone challenges that definition, when all automatically becomes obvious, proving the challenger to be something other than politically correct.

Comment: No one ever thinks of charting this: If you place the identifying word in a horizontal list (straight, gay, bi-sexual, transexual, transgender and  pansexual) and then put the choice of whom they are attracted to after their identity, that would answer the question. What you "are" and who you "are attracted to".

Comment: [The New York Times has a recent article about this](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/21/style/lgbtq-gender-language.html).

Answer (score 12):

The other answers are well-taken. To attempt a tl;dr:

> **Q1.** What *is* the difference between a bisexual and a pansexual?

The people? **Probably nothing**. But the difference between the ***terms*** '[bisexual](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/19448)' and '[pansexual](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/136944)' is that the former **implicitly assumes** two genders ('binary gender') or attraction to only two genders while the latter implies that there are more (possibly many more) than 'male' and 'female'. People who identify as pansexual may not have issues with bisexuals *per se* but probably consider their own terminology *more inclusive* of the [genderqueer](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/77468?redirectedFrom=genderqueer#eid237081402).

> **Q2.** Why is there no agreement in the LGTBQ community for a single, simple term to express this gender and sexual preference?

**1st**, because people disagree about language choices *all the time* for no good reason at all. All the moreso when so many neologisms are dealing so closely with identity, sexuality, and politics. **2nd**, because 'the LGTBQ community' is *an expression*, not an actual gang that has regular conferences with a steering committee to hash out things in the interim. **3rd**, because those terms, especially as self-applied, are not precisely overlapping and do not imply a new set third gender but an openness to either conceiving of more than two or personally ignoring them, whatever and however many they are.

Answer (score 10):

> Q2. Why is there no agreement in the LGTBQ community for a single, simple term to express this gender and sexual preference?

A2. Because the LGTBQ is not a single speech community, that's why.

A speech community -- a bunch of people who talk (mostly) with one another -- is where agreements on single terms take place subliminally, and they have already taken place in the various real speech communities that constitute the membership of a brand-new sociopolitical merger so diverse that we need a five-letter acronym for it.

All over the world there are local L,G,T,B, and Q speech communities (sometimes not formally united, or simply not socially connected, into LGTBQ. Yet.) And they have been there for a long time.  Many speak English. They have their own speech terms and their own meanings to go with them and their own histories and mythologies. These things don't blend together coherently very fast, especially under social pressure.

So it's unlikely that there **are** -- or even could be -- any single, simple terms so early. At this stage of development the norm is evanescent pansemantic trans/meaning-fluid terms.

Comment: So, to sum up, you're talking about EPT/MF terms.

Answer (score 5):

I want to specifically address the first question in a way that it hasn't been yet.

> Q 1. What is the difference between a bisexual and a pansexual?

*Bisexualism* works only in a context where gender is binary. It assumes that people are only one of two possible genders—and that if you are bisexual you are attracted to both. But gender neutrality eliminates this dichotomy altogether.

(Note, too, that the distinction we now make between *sex* and *gender* is something only relatively recent.)

There are people who positively identify as gender-neutral (or as a non-binary gender). They do not consider themselves to be either gender. And while some *may* identify with various components on a sliding scale or spectrum (with one gender at one end and another gender at the other end), others consider themselves to have no gender identity at all, and still others consider themselves to have an identity that is simply "outside" any such binary scale.

In other words, some people who are gender neutral reject not only two possible genders but also the idea of a defining spectrum *between* two genders. (At least with respect to themselves.)

From an interesting article called "[10 things you always wanted to know about being non-binary but were afraid to ask](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/prince-edward-island/pei-non-binary-gender-sexuality-rory-starkman-russell-louder-1.4495208)":

> If you're looking at gender on a spectrum from male to female, *non-binary could be anywhere outside of that spectrum* [emphasis mine] or in between the male and female.

So, coming back to *pansexualism*, it *may* be somewhat misleading to say that somebody who is pansexual is attracted to all people "regardless of where they fit on a spectrum" (unless you also include everybody who isn't on that spectrum). Instead, I would say that they are simply attracted to people period, regardless of gender identity or non-identity.

---

Here is some additional information, as pulled from comments.

Although Dictionary.com says that a *bissexual* is attracted *to people of various gender identities*, both Merriam-Webster and Oxford continue to explicitly use a binary definition for the word. At least traditionally, a bisexual is attracted to both men and women. But (by some definitions), they would not be attracted to somebody who doesn't identify as male or female.

Practically speaking, *bisexualism* might amount to the same thing as *pansexualism*. But still, there is a logical distinction between "I like all colours" and "colour is irrelevant."

The definition of pansexual provided in the question states (the emphasis is mine) that: "Pansexual people may refer to themselves as **gender-blind**, asserting that **gender and sex are not determining factors in their romantic or sexual attraction to others**."

Somebody who is colour blind is literally not influenced by the choice of those colours they can't distinguish—except intellectually. That's what's meant by "gender blind" when it comes to pansexuality. Bisexuals can differentiate between genders (although they are attracted to both); but pansexuals simply don't differentiate between them at all (aside from intellectually).

To reuse an analogy from a different answer, I like steak and I like pasta. But when I go to a restaurant that has both on the menu, I decide which of those I want to eat on that particular night—which one I'm more in the mood for. However, for somebody without taste buds (somebody who is "taste blind") the flavour of those two menu items will have no bearing on their choice. For them, based on taste alone, the two are indistinguishable, and they might as well be contemplating the same thing. They will make their decision based on other factors (price, calories, size, and so on).

Similarly, consider a bisexual who's presented with a choice between a man and a woman. While they are attracted to both, they might be feeling more *partial* to one gender. It likely won't be the only factor in their choice of partner, but it will be at least *a* factor.

For a pansexual, who is "gender blind," it won't be a factor at all. They won't feel any more *partial* to a particular gender than any other at any given time, simply because it's not part of their perception. They are simply unaware of gender in any way—aside from intellectually. For them, their choice in partner is only (and always) about all of the non-gender factors.

---

As for the second question, this culture, and the terminology behind it, is so new that language and attitudes haven't yet had time to "shake out" into a cohesive consensus yet. That there is no agreement comes down to the timing of adoption.

(It was only in 2017 that both *The Chicago Manual of Style* and the *Associated Press Stylebook* acknowledged the use of *they* and *their* (and even *themself*) as an acceptable form of gender-neutral third-person pronoun if required—but *in particular* when used in the context of people who use it as part of their identify as having a non-binary gender.)

Comment: Aren't bisexuals also attracted to people regardless of their gender or sex? They feel sexual attraction and fall in love with the person, it doesn't matter if that person is a man, woman, or a transgender. Dictionary.com says: *"to people of various gender identities"*

Comment: @Mari-LouA I took the comment discussion and used it to update my answer.

Comment: But hey this is ELU.

Comment: Fwiw, 'pansexual' is not actually perfectly synonymous with 'gender-blind' and *might* have romantic preferences while still remaining open to people of all genders. That would particularly be the case for people of liberal sexuality who feel 'bisexual' in and of itself is offensively binary.

Comment: Pan means all, so pansexual cannot mean gender blind. On the contrary, it would mean sexual in all ways, without any one particular feature defining it. So for me, this: [...]"asserting that gender and sex are not determining factors in their romantic or sexual attraction to others". Seriously, how can sex and gender not be **in some manner** related to romantic or sexual attraction??  Everything might not count for sure, but I don't see how none of it can count and still be romantic or sexual attraction! If that were so, it's no longer romantic or sexual attraction.  It is something else...

Answer (score 4):

Regarding question 1:

I think it's a matter of carefully reading the definitions. Bisexual means to be attracted to both men and women. Pansexual means to be attracted to people regardless of sex or gender identity.

To illustrate the difference, let's use food (because it's more relatable). Suppose you like pizza and pasta specifically then you could say you like both of those foods (possibly for different reasons). You could also like pizza and pasta **because** they are Italian food, you don't care about their difference, the mere fact that it's Italian does it for you.

The first example could be compared to bisexuality, they like both men and woman, possibly for different reasons. The term pansexual emphasises that they like both without emphasis on the gender. Think of the statement 'I like all Italian food', if you consider pizza and pasta Italian, then you like both of the specific examples. Having said that, the first is a subset of the latter. All pansexuals are also bisexual, but not all bisexuals have to be pansexuals.

Regarding question 2:

You already mentioned the term community, which is a good start for an answer. The community, in this case, is not organised like a government with one view point. To compare it with politics: take conservatives in the UK, they have mostly the same view points and are pressured to follow the party line.

Now look at the broader community, all conservatives in the world, they you could identify many sub-communities (the Conservative Party in the UK, the Republicans in the US, and so on for all the different countries, perhaps even multiple communities for a single country). As an outsider, two conservatives are just two conservatives, but on closer inspection they might turn out to have widely varying views.

The same goes for the LGBTQ community (or any other group of people defined by one thing: men, women, Americans, politicians, environmentalists, liberals, children, the elderly). In fact, I think you'll have difficulty finding any subset of people defined by one thing who almost unanimously agree on anything (why that is might be better suited for psychology.se, biology.se, or philosophy.se but even then you might not get all of them to agree on one answer ;) ).

Answer (score 3):

Gender and sexuality are a spectrum.  Many people do not identify solely as male or female or solely as straight, gay or bisexual.  There's quite a bit of room in between and around these terms.  This necesitates more diversity of language when talking about one's gender or sexuality.

1. The difference between the terms bisexual and pansexual will differ depending on who you talk to.  Pansexuality is the attraction to those on any part of gender spectrum, where as bisexualuality is the attration to both men and women.  I suspect some folks using the term bisexual to describe themselves would also fall into the pansexual group as well, they just choose the more well known word.
2. Gender fluid does not mean that an individual doesn't want to be identified as a man or woman, in fact, the fluidity may very well be between being a man and woman.  Gender fluidity doesn't imply a lack of gender, just that the gender can change. Agender, nongendered, genderless and genderfree actually do mean someone doesn't identify with any gender.  As for the reason why there are so many terms? Transexual and transgender people are still not as accepted as other groups in the population at large.  A lack of visibility and wide acceptance has made it so no one term is the dominant one for those who don't identify with the binary system.

Comment: Let's restrict the discussion to the language aspect. It's better, too, if you can cite your sources so this may qualify as an answer, and not a comment.

Comment: There are a few insignificant typos in an otherwise well-written answer. I'd edit the answer myself, but seeing as I am the OP it seems inappropriate for me to do so.

Comment: “[whereas bisexuality] is the attration to both men and women” — Not if you ask most bisexual people. This wording limits the scope of attraction to the two binary sexes/genders, which is one of the things many bisexual people point out as a commonly held and often propagated, but inaccurate, beliefs about bisexuality.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Can you elaborate? You've said 'No, that's wrong' but you haven't given what's right. It almost seems as though your correction would actually give a definition of 'pansexual'.

Comment: @Mitch That’s always been the problem for me too. The way most people who identify as bisexual nowadays view the term, its definition is close enough to that of pansexuality that I am unable to describe the difference. They say that bisexuality does not imply only two genders (rather, the ‘two’ is 1. their own gender + 2. anything else), but I also cannot see how the end result differs from pansexuality in practical terms.

Comment: @Mitch The [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pansexuality#Comparison_to_bisexuality_and_other_sexual_identities) you unearthed in your comment above is a good example—it shows just how tangled-up these terms (and notions) all are, and how difficult it can be to gain any kind of clarity. It’s about as clear as what bi-identifying people I’ve talked to have told me, and ends up leaving me just as unclear as they have.

Comment: Bisexual literally has the Latinate prefix 'bi' in it, meaning 'two'. Also, gender and sexuality are SOMETIMES seen by SOME people as a spectrum. I would wager the majority of the population do not see them as a spectrum.

Comment: These questions are so much easier when people stop pcing around. One thing is what or whom you identify with and another is who you want to have sex with.

Answer (score 3):

- Bisexuality *sensu lato* (in the broad sense) means that one is sexually attracted to both males and females; it makes no distinction as to whether or not one is sexually attracted to persons who are neither male nor female.

  - Bisexuality *sensu stricto* (in the narrow sense) means that one is sexually attracted to males and females, but *not* to non-male non-female persons.
  - Pansexuality means that one is sexually attracted to persons of all genders.

If gender is regarded as a spectrum, with more possible values than just MALE and FEMALE, a pansexual person would be bisexual *senso lato*, due to being sexually attracted to both males and females, but would not be bisexual *senso stricto*, due to also being attracted to non-male non-females.

If gender is regarded as strictly binary, with the only possible values being MALE and FEMALE, the distinction between the two subcategories of bisexuality *sensu lato* disappears, and bisexuality and pansexuality become synonymous.

Comment: This is not correct, at least not going by how many/most bisexuals define the term nowadays. There is nothing in any broad or narrow sense of the word _bisexual_ that implies ‘male’ or ‘female’—in fact, there are no broad and narrow senses of the word at all. Roughly, _homosexual_ means ‘attracted to the same [gender/sex]’; _heterosexual_ means ‘attracted to a/the different [gender(s)/sex(es)]’; and _bisexual_ means ‘attracted to both the same [gender/sex] and a/the different [gender(s)/sex(es)]’. The _bi-_ part does refer to male + female, but to same (_homo-_) + different (_hetero-_).

Answer (score -1):

The difference between Pansexual and Bisexual can be explained like this.

Not all heterosexuals focus on lust when selecting a spouse.  For some people,  hetero, gay and pan, the emphasis is on being in love, and in a committed "forever" relationship.  Many do not consumate their relationships sexually until vows are exchanged.  People who are head over heels in love, may glimpse the Pan reality...  Would you be less in love if your special darling was born a different gender?

By comparison, many people seek sexual relationships... or relationships that begin with sex.  For these people, regardless of sexual orientation; desire, attraction and lust, are what it's all about.  The physicality is important.  Sometimes gender, colour, stature, size, clothing, muscle tone and even hairlessness can be some of the physical attributes that are judged in the selection of a partner.   What prospective mates physically look like, is a huge priority.  Bisexual people are sexually attracted to/by either/both/all genders.

Pan people are far less likely to be put off someone because of any physical trait, including a lack of genitalia.